# conversion of python dictionary to json types in django rest framework

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

This is a question of comprehension rather than code issue. I am using DRF for a year. When I learnt about serializers, it says there are two steps.

For get request what serializer class do is:

1. Converting complex datatypes like queryset into python datatype like the dictionary.
2. Converting dictionary into json format which is sent to the api as response.

I use print commands to see everything what is happening or using the shell. I can see the first step happening ie I can see the complex queryset and after serialization can see the dictionary of the queryset. But nowhere in the code I can see the second step happening. Although the json format isnt very different from the python dictionary. The only difference I see is the double quotes instead of single quote in json. But still, the conversion needs to happen. Is it happening automatically or am I missing something here??

My snippet:

[image]

My prints of the queryset and serialized data:

[image]

Here, the email printed is the complex data. After serialization it is converted to python dictionary. However, the JSON data coming into postman is like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being handled by [**Response** class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#responses).
`Response` class takes [unrendered, serialized data of the response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#data) and [status code as argument](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#status_code). If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/response.py#L70) it chooses the [render classes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers) based on the [`accepted_media_type`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#accepted_media_type). By default django support following renderers by default.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

In your case django [uses `JSONRenderer` class](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1fa5bc31c0c047eb2109929b17f8e53e84b7d40b/rest_framework/renderers.py#L53) which has a [`render` method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1fa5bc31c0c047eb2109929b17f8e53e84b7d40b/rest_framework/renderers.py#L85) which does the [actual serialization into JSON](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1fa5bc31c0c047eb2109929b17f8e53e84b7d40b/rest_framework/renderers.py#L100)

Comment: Very very good explanation Abdul. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Serializer.data` gives you an instance of `rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict` which is just a light-weight wrapper around `OrderedDict`. `OrderedDict` is a further extension of Python's `dict` specialized for maintaining the insertion order of keys. As JSON is a text-based format for transferring data, the `OrderedDict` instance corresponding to the serializer is first stringified and then sent. As JSON is a standardized format, the browser is able to parse the string representation and pretty print it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).